# How to assign the array data to variables?

Tags: data, variable-definitions, list-manipulation

A very basic question but puzzled me for long time on how to assign array to variables. For instance, we have array 
    {{t1,x1},{t2,x2}...{tn,xn}}
how to assign the first element to variable t and second to variable x so I can do fitting for x=f(t)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myData = {{t1,x1},{t2,x2},{t3,x3}};

{t,x} = Transpose[myData];

t
```

{t1,t2,t3}

But are you seeking `myFit = Fit[myData, {t^3, t^2, t, 1}, x]` (for instance)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. that works! And yes I am looking for findfit with known expression but unknown parameters. Because the expression involves integration from 0 to current value of x, that causes trouble.

Comment: But thanks for your help, it solves my data handling problem.